# Extracting a URL from within a string

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch

My app receives numerous text strings which may or may not contain a URL anywhere within the string. What would be the best method to extract a URL from within a string? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The BSD-licensed AutoHyperlinks framework](http://trac.adium.im/wiki/AutoHyperlinksFramework) provides classes to scan text for URLs and either return them to you or mark them up as links in an attributed string.

I don't think it builds out of the box for the iPhone, but you could always add preprocessor directives to cut out any AppKit-dependent code. The scan-and-return interface should just work, once you get it to build. (Make sure to run the tests.)

[Mike Abdullah wrote a patch for iPhone support.](http://trac.adium.im/ticket/10594) You might try that.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but judging by the number of errors and warnings generated, it will require a significant amount work to get this working on the iPhone -

Comment: JK: That can be misleading. A single line of code can produce a lot of errors if it's sufficiently uncompilable, but it's still only one line of code. I think the AppKit-dependent parts of AutoHyperlinks are isolated enough that you could conditionalize them out fairly easily.

Comment: Thanks Peter. I'll give the patch a try tomorrow.

Answer (score 8):

If you are working on a Mac application, Mac OS X 10.6 offers a new API to let you detect URLs with the spell checker. You may do it this way.

```
NSString *s = @"http://example.com"
NSInteger wordCount = 0;
NSOrthography *orthography = nil;
NSArray *checkResults = [[NSSpellChecker sharedSpellChecker] checkString:s range:NSMakeRange(0, [s length]) types:NSTextCheckingTypeLink options:nil inSpellDocumentWithTag:0 orthography:&orthography wordCount:&wordCount];
for (NSTextCheckingResult *result in checkResults) {
    NSRange range = result.range;
    NSURL *URL = result.URL;
}
```

Comment: This is definitely preferable to bringing in a dedicated framework if you can. Note that you don't actually care about word count of orthography usually when searching for links, so just pass in a `NULL` pointer for efficiency.

Comment: I've also implemented this in our open source KSFileUtilities code: https://github.com/karelia/KSFileUtilities/commit/4ef561512fab9a169fcf63129037bfddfda6257b